# Bash HereDoc variable Error on MacBook with newline characters

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I have a script that happily runs on Ubuntu 22.04 with Bash. However, the same script starts giving errors when executed under bash (v 5.2) on an Arm MacBook.

Below is the problematic piece of the script:

```
my_script=$(cat <<EOF
while getopts \":lr:e:\" option; do \n
  case \\\${option} in \n
     l) \n
        cat file.txt \n
        exit;; \n
     e) \n
        vi file.txt \n
        exit;; \n
     r)  \nB
         rm file.txt \n
        exit;; \n
\n
     *) \n
       echo \"invalid option. \" \n
     exit;; \n
  esac \n
done \n

EOF
)
```

The plan is to dump this variable into a file as a standalone script so it should preserve the formatting however, I am running into below error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
```

Can someone please suggest why bash is complaining for this ?
This is how I am writing the script to a file:
`printf \"${my_script}\"> my_script_file`

Comment: Why would you do such a thing in the first place? Use `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF` and you don't need any of that nasty escaping.

Comment: And with _both_ of them the `\"`s and `\n`s are wrong; you can just use `"` without any escaping in a heredoc, and newlines stay newlines with no need for any `\n`

Comment: Even beyond that, in a strong majority of cases it's unnecessary and inappropriate to put code in a heredoc in the first place. Put that code _in a function_ -- say, `child_script() { ... }` and you can use something like `printf '%s\n' "$(declare -f child_script)" 'child_script "$@"' >new_file` to write that function's definition out to a file that invokes it when run. That way all your normal static-checking tools (https://www.shellcheck.net/, https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server, etc) work as normal.

Comment: Beyond that -- make sure you're giving us a [mre] -- code you've tested to cause the problem you're asking about when run _on its own_ with no additions or changes. Right now I don't know how you're writing the variable out to a file, and the details (using `echo`? If so, with what quoting and which arguments?) matter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the suggestions. This is how I write the code to file:
```
printf \"${my_script}\"> my_script_file
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to add details there, please -- comments don't allow proper multi-line formatting, and also aren't considered "part of the question" for history/archival purposes.

Comment: Ah. Use `printf '%s\n' "$my_script"` instead, so the script is treated as data instead of as a format string. (You'll _also_ want to fix the way you define the variable as described in the very first comment, switching to a quoted heredoc and taking out all the escaping, if you don't follow the function-definition + `declare -f` advice).

Comment: Also, note the lack of backslashes in front of the quotes in `"$my_script"` -- when you add backslashes in front of those quotes you change them from syntactic quotes to literal ones. Only syntactic quotes prevent unwanted word-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: **Writing it to a file** certainly won't produce the syntax error you mentioned. If the error happens when **assigning** to the variable, provide a minimal example for your case.

Comment: @user1934428, ...I read the OP to mean that _running_ the file that has been written to produces the error at hand. Which... I believe; there's a lot of undefined behavior their code relies on (f/e, the details of how printf handles undefined escape sequences is something I wouldn't be surprised to see having changed between the relevant bash versions; but if we just tell them how to write code that depends only on well-defined behavior, then any need to investigate undefined behavior becomes mooted).

Comment: @sbunny, ...the other thing is that if you _do_ perform that expansion in an unquoted context (and because `\"$my_script\"` is surrounding the expansion results with literal quotes instead of syntactic quotes, they leave it for syntax purposes as an unquoted expansion), it gets split into separate words, and `printf` treats the first word in its arguments as a format string and subsequent arguments as values to use to fill out placeholders in that format string. So if you are in fact escaping the quotes as you showed, that's a _lot_ of unnecessary weirdness.

Comment: `myscript="..."` would be much simpler; you can embed newlines in a variable assignment like this.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : _to mean that running the file that has been written to produces the error_ : But this does not make sense to me! Why then not creating the file with a text editor, and then invoke it with the required parameter. And, if it is really by **running** this file, that the error is produced, I wonder why the OP is then not posting the code in this file, which would be more interesting for debugging than the code to create a variable which is then sent to a file.

Comment: @user1934428, agreed. Inspecting that content by hand would, in and of itself, help them ask a more narrowly focused question (about how its actual and intended content differ if it's not being written out the way they expect; or about why that actual content doesn't result in desired runtime behavior, if it _is_ written the way they expect), instead of requiring readers to figure out first what the actual output is (which depends on details like how the exact version of bash they're running in each environment handles invalid escape sequences) and second why that output isn't valid code.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you're taking is so error-prone that going into exactly *how* it fails is dependent on details I don't think it would be worthwhile to delve.

There are several better ways to do this.

---

## Use A Function

This has the distinct and significant advantage that static-checking tools can validate your syntax when checking the parent script, vs needing to use them to open the generated child script.

```
# define the function we want to write in our existing local shell
my_script() {
  while getopts ":lr:e:" option; do
    case ${option} in
       l) cat file.txt; exit;;
       e) vi file.txt; exit;;
       r) rm file.txt; exit;;
       *) echo "invalid option" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
  done
}

# write shebang, function text, and a function invocation to a file
printf '%s\n' \
  '#!/usr/bin/env bash' \
  "$(declare -f my_script)" \
  'my_script "$@"' \
  >file
```

---

## Use A Quoted Heredoc

Using `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF` tells the shell not to try to run any expansions, but instead to keep your heredoc content *exactly* as previously defined.

Combining this with storing an exact copy of that heredoc in your output file (which you get with `cat`, or if it's in a variable, `printf '%s\n' "$variable"`, but *not* with `echo "$variable"` or `printf "$variable"`) and the need to worry about how unescaping occurs is mooted.

```
cat >file <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while getopts ":lr:e:" option; do
  case ${option} in
     l) cat file.txt; exit;;
     e) vi file.txt; exit;;
     r) rm file.txt; exit;;
     *) echo "invalid option" >&2; exit 1;;
  esac
done
EOF
```